Why does my unmanaged bag return an incorrect value? Possible problem with aligned offset calculation
I have created this unmanaged bag data holder that would allow me to use it inside strictly unmanaged contexts. However, there seems to be some issue with the alignment I think. I just can't figure out what it is...
This is the entire struct code:
using System;
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe;

namespace Game.Runtime.Utility
{
    public struct BagUnmanaged : IDisposable
    {
        private NativeList<byte> data;
        private NativeList<int>  offsets;
        
        private int currentOffset;

        public BagUnmanaged(Allocator allocator)
        {
            data    = new NativeList<byte>(allocator);
            offsets = new NativeList<int>(allocator);
            
            currentOffset = 0;
        }

        private int AlignOffset(int offset, int alignment)
        {
            return (offset + (alignment - 1)) & ~(alignment - 1);
        }
        public unsafe void Add<T>(T value) where T : unmanaged
        {
            int size = UnsafeUtility.SizeOf<T>();
            int alignment = UnsafeUtility.AlignOf<T>();
        
            currentOffset = AlignOffset(currentOffset, alignment);

            offsets.Add(currentOffset);

            data.ResizeUninitialized(currentOffset + size);

            byte* ptr = data.GetUnsafePtr();
            UnsafeUtility.CopyStructureToPtr(ref value, ptr + currentOffset);

            currentOffset += size;
        }

        public unsafe T Get<T>(int index) where T : unmanaged
        {
            int   elementOffset = offsets[index];
            byte* ptr           = data.GetUnsafeReadOnlyPtr();
            
            return UnsafeUtility.ReadArrayElementWithStride<T>(ptr, elementOffset, UnsafeUtility.SizeOf<T>());
        }
        public unsafe void Set<T>(int index, T value) where T : unmanaged
        {
            int   elementOffset = offsets[index];
            byte* ptr           = data.GetUnsafePtr();
            
            UnsafeUtility.CopyStructureToPtr(ref value, ptr + elementOffset);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (data.IsCreated)
            { data.Dispose(); }
            
            if (offsets.IsCreated)
            { offsets.Dispose(); }
        }
    }
}

I have tested it and both float and bool values seem to be correct when I get them from the bag, however, the int value after adding it and after updating it comes out completely wrong.
private void Start()
{
    using BagUnmanaged bag = new(Allocator.Persistent);
    
    bag.Add(5.0F);
    bag.Add(1);
    bag.Add(true);

    var f = bag.Get<float>(0);
    var i = bag.Get<int>(1);
    var b = bag.Get<bool>(2);
    
    Console.WriteLine("Float {0}", f);
    Console.WriteLine("Int {0}", i); // Returns sometimes 0 sometimes -1 or 80
    Console.WriteLine("Boolean {0}", b);
    
    bag.Set(1, 90);
    
    i = bag.Get<int>(1);
    
    Console.WriteLine("Updated Int {0}", i); // Same incorrect value as above
}


Can you edit your question to include the logic behing AlignOffset, that seems like a very strange operation to me...

Id say the same, the offset surely would be as simple as the "currentoffset" for that index of item in the other list. No more complex than that.

I'm curious as to the requirement or usecase for this to be unmanaged/unsafe.  There are a few ways to achieve this without stepping into unmanaged memory territory. Are there strict constraints you are trying to fit?

Writing the bytes seems to be fine, I just tested it by printing out the raw bytes (little endian):
00 00 a0 40 01 00 00 00 01
---float--- ----int---- -b-

So the problem has to be with your Get function. Which it is, your problem lies in using UnsafeUtility.ReadArrayElementWithStride.
ReadArrayElementWithStride(destination, index, stride, value) is a method that calls Write(destination + index * stride, value). The "stride" parameter is the width of the elements contained in the array (assuming all the same size!), multiplied with the index to get an offset. So the second parameter isn't an offset, it's an index, causing the float to be fine (index of 0), but every index after that reads way out-of-bounds. Testing with a bool as your final type makes it seem like it's an issue with only the int, since any given out-of-bounds byte will most likely not be 00.
Fixing this would just involve changing your reading logic to using UnsafeUtility.CopyPtrToStructure, the counterpart to UnsafeUtility.CopyStructureToPtr:
public unsafe T Get<T>(int index) where T : unmanaged {
    ...
    UnsafeUtility.CopyPtrToStructure(ptr + elementOffset, out T result);
    return result;
}

